# Full System Linux backup with rsync via ssh to other computer

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, sudo, rsync

I would like to do a full system backup analogously to this thread:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system

...however, not with creating tarballs, but with rsync - and from one computer to the other over local network, via ssh. I have followed the steps and in principle, it works ok up to some point, where probably, file permissions play a role.

I have set up the rsync as follows:

`rsync -aAXv userOnSource@sourceIP:/ /home/MYBACKUPFOLDER`

I will exclude certain folders like /sys and /proc (as one should) next time, but the problem lies in the fact that also, some folders in e.g. */etc* and */usr/share* throw a permission denied error and aren't copied.

My question is thus:
How do I set up rsync such that it copies everything desired, and given that I renew my old computer with the same linux distribution (in my case, ArchLinux) and create the same users, how do I preserve the file attributes and permissions when I copy back the backup to the newly installed machine?

Pro question: What else would be needed if I have yet a third machine to send the backup to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my script,fyi.

```sh
sudo rsync -avAX --delete --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found","/swapfile","/home/*/.thumbnails/*","/home/*/.cache/*"} / /mnt/rootfs
```

Would suggest to consider the following steps,

1. Do disk/partition clone if possible;
2. Run the above script on source PC, otherwise SSH config may cause issues for root user access;
3. Backup to mounted USB harddisk or local foler (must be excluded) if possible, later you will have option to compress it before transfer out.

Comment: Thanks @balun, I will try, especially with your suggestion no. 2. Let's see what it does, will tell whether it worked or not.

Comment: It worked with rsync according ti your suggestions, also via ssh to a server PC. Thanks :-) I also needed to set "PermitRootLogin yes" on the server machine in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. So, if my old computer dies, I can just install an new Arch Linux on another computer, rsync the backup there, and everything is as it was?